# _csv.Error: line contains NUL with german characters csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding, utf-8

I've created a csv file with german letters(umlauts) and i need to specify this file and get a new one. All steps in script goes well when I don't use german letters in csv, but if i do the same for the german csv - I recieve an error message `_csv.Error: line contains NUL`.
Here's the script I'm working on:

```
import csv


with open("products3.csv", newline='') as r_file:
    # Creates object reader, with separator in you csv file ";"
    file_reader = csv.reader(r_file, delimiter = ";")
    #Be carefull with encoding, set the needed (utf-8 by default)
    with open("products_new.csv", mode="w", newline='') as w_file:
        file_writer = csv.writer(w_file, delimiter = ";")
        # Counter for products(rows in file)
        count = 0
        # Loop through products(rows) in file
        for row in file_reader:
            #if 24th row(Image Src) contains ";"(you can specify the separator with yours) - it means that we have more than one image src
            if row[24].find(';') != -1:
                img_srcs =  row[24].split(';')
                handle = row[0]
                #We left first row with whole info about the product but we change the Image Src node to contain first link only
                row[24] = img_srcs[0] 
                file_writer.writerow(row)
                index = 0
                for img in img_srcs:
                    #In my template if there's only one link, nevertheless empty separated links may occur so I prevent this
                    if img != " ":
                        #As we already wrote first row with first image link, we don't need to repeat it
                        if index != 0:
                            new_row = ['%s'%handle, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
                            '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '%s'%img, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
                            file_writer.writerow(new_row)
                    index += 1
            else:
                #if we dont have any link in Image Src we just add this row to the new file
                file_writer.writerow(row)
            count += 1


            #If you have empty rows just specify this value with the real amount of rows in your template
            if count == 3158:
                break
        print(f'Total products in file: {count}')

r_file.close()
w_file.close()
```

I've tried to use utf-8/16, utf-16-le/be, utf-8-sig, ISO-***, Windows encodings - but still no result.
How do I get this german csv file? I had an .xlsx file, then I converted it to utf-8 .txt file, and after that I converted it to the .csv file with encoding UTF-16 LE(bcs just converting in Excel form .xlsx to .csv - not working correctly and german umlauts becomes "?").
So what can i do let python read .csv file with german letters or how can I convert form .xlsx to .csv with utf-8?
Error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Desktop\paste_json\csv_translate.py", line 19, in <module>
    for row in file_reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

A few lines on csv file:

```
    Handle  Title   Body (HTML) Vendor  Type    Tags    Published   Option1 Name    Option1 Value   Option2 Name    Option2 Value   Option3 Name    Option3 Value   Variant SKU Variant Grams   Variant Inventory Tracker   Variant Inventory Qty   Variant Inventory Policy    Variant Fulfillment Service Variant Price   Variant Compare At Price    Variant Requires Shipping   Variant Taxable Variant Barcode Image Src   Image Position  Image Alt Text  Gift Card   SEO Title   SEO Description Google Shopping / Google Product Category   Google Shopping / Gender    Google Shopping / Age Group Google Shopping / MPN   Google Shopping / AdWords Grouping  Google Shopping / AdWords Labels    Google Shopping / Condition Google Shopping / Custom Product    Google Shopping / Custom Label 0    Google Shopping / Custom Label 1    Google Shopping / Custom Label 2    Google Shopping / Custom Label 3    Google Shopping / Custom Label 4    Variant Image   Variant Weight Unit Variant Tax Code    Cost per item   Status
92011280    Ring aus 925 Silber mit Blautopasen und Zirkonia Steinen    "Artikelnr.:92011280;Marke:SOKOLOV;Für:Damen;circa Gewicht:1,914;Metall:Silber;Legierung:925;Beschichtung:Rhodinierung;Steinbesatz:Topas;Anzahl:3;Schliffform:Ovalschliff;Farbe:Hellblau;Steinbesatz:Zirkonia;Anzahl:8;Schliffform:Rundschliff;Farbe:Farblos"   SOKOLOV Ring    SOKOLOV,Silber,Rhodinierung,Ringe,Dekorativ,Topas,Damen TRUE    Grosse  16,5                    92011280-16.5   1.89    shopify 0   deny    manual  49      TRUE    TRUE        "https://pmdn.sokolov.io/pics/FF/A5/6A893B1228B88D675651D89E034A.jpg; https://pmdn.sokolov.io/pics/95/D1/89AA497A98814FA2A1C6ACAA662D.jpg; https://pmdn.sokolov.io/pics/04/DA/4FADCDEABDC4E4207825495B056D.jpg"         LIE         Damen > Schmuck > Silber > Ring                                                     g           
92011280    Ring aus 925 Silber mit Blautopasen und Zirkonia Steinen    "Artikelnr.:92011280;Marke:SOKOLOV;Für:Damen;circa Gewicht:1,914;Metall:Silber;Legierung:925;Beschichtung:Rhodinierung;Steinbesatz:Topas;Anzahl:3;Schliffform:Ovalschliff;Farbe:Hellblau;Steinbesatz:Zirkonia;Anzahl:8;Schliffform:Rundschliff;Farbe:Farblos"   SOKOLOV Ring    SOKOLOV,Silber,Rhodinierung,Ringe,Dekorativ,Topas,Damen TRUE    Grosse  17                  92011280-17 1.9 shopify 0   deny    manual  49      TRUE    TRUE                    LIE         Damen > Schmuck > Silber > Ring                                                     g
```

Comment: Provide the full error traceback and a few lines from `products3.csv` to reproduce the issue.  It's not clear but sounds like you encoded `products3.csv` with `utf-16le` and should use that encoding to open the file.  That would explain the "line contains NUL" error message.

Comment: Note, a google sheet link doesn't help.  Post the *text* of product.csv in the question and let us know the encoding used.

Comment: Why so complicated? * had an .xlsx file, then I **converted it to utf-8 .txt file**, and after that I **converted it to the .csv file with encoding UTF-16 LE***. Maybe you could add _converting_ scripts/procedures to your [mcve]? BTW, export from Excel sheet to a CSV should work fine (specify encoding)…

Comment: When just converting from xlsx to csv - csv than don't see german umlauts

Comment: "a few lines"...  A question should stand on its own.  BTW, I downloaded the Google Sheets links as CSV and it was in UTF-8 and displayed everything fine.   Probably a viewer issue and not an issue with the file.  Your posted code has errors (delimiter can't be two spaces, for example), but fixing those it ran fine as well.

Comment: The error on that line means the CSV file should be opened with `encoding='utf-16le'`.  You should also open both files with `newline=''` per the `csv` documentation, and then you won't have to mess with the `lineterminator` in the `csv.writer`.  Also no need to `.close()` the files when using `with`, and look up `enumerate` for use in counting lines.

Comment: delimiter was replaced a few times, it was just for testing purposes, and for ussual it works with ";" with english. And all the code also works with other non-german files